# QT C++ Read MotionJpeg flux

Tags: qt5, mjpeg

I would like to read a motionjpeg flux from my rasbperry camera to a QT interface. How can I achieve that ? Is there any sample code that show how to get the flux and display it ?
I have QT 5.2 and I'm using QML.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you tell me what motionjpeg is?

Comment: Bitstream encoding for video in which each frame is compressed using the JPEG still-image compression algorithm

Comment: I think that task is low level and so it is most likely done by the backend that uses Qt.